# I need to access a value from one class using AID

Tags: java, agents-jade

I'm stuck with a Jade-agent problem that doesn't let me continue with the signature practice.

The problem is the following:

I have two basic agents: a seller and a buyer. There could be more than one of each. They communicate with JADE protocols. The seller say the price of the product, and the buyer buy it. So, I decided to implement a HashMap in the buyer agent, cause the seller has an associated price, so when the buyer wants to search Seller Agents, they are stored in a hashmap. In the hashmap, the key is the AID of the agent and the value, the price of the product he sells (it is a Seller local variable). But when I want to access the price of the product, I don't know the way to get it.

---

### Seller Agent.

```
public class SellerAgent extends Agent {

    private ArrayList<String> messages;  // Messages between them are stored in ArrayList.
    int price;  // Price of the product.


    // setup() and takeDown().
    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        messages= new ArrayList();
        price = rnd.nextInt(50);

        // Agent registration
        ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription();
        sd.setType("GUI");
        sd.setName("Seller");

        DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
        dfd.setName(getAID());
        dfd.addServices(sd);

        try {
            DFService.register(this, dfd);
        } catch (FIPAException fe) {
            fe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void takeDown() {
        try {
            DFService.deregister(this);
        } catch (FIPAException fe) {
            fe.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("END OF " + this.getName());
    }

    public Integer getPrice() { return price; }
}
```

---

### Buyer Agent.

```
public class BuyerAgent extends Agent {

    private HashMap<AID, Integer> sellers;  // Sellers.
    private ArrayList<String> messages;   // Messages between them are stored in ArrayList.


    @Override
    protected void setup() {
        sellers = new HashMap();
        messages = new ArrayList();

        // Agent registration
        ServiceDescription sd = new ServiceDescription();
        sd.setType("GUI");
        sd.setName("Buye");

        DFAgentDescription dfd = new DFAgentDescription();
        dfd.setName(getAID());
        dfd.addServices(sd);

        try {
                DFService.register(this, dfd);
        } catch (FIPAException fe) {
                fe.printStackTrace();
        }

        // SearchAgents Task.
        addBehaviour(new SearchAgents(this, 5000));           // Search Seller Agent.
    }

    @Override
    protected void takeDown() {
        try {
            DFService.deregister(this);
        } catch (FIPAException fe) {
            fe.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("END OF " + this.getName());
    }


    public class SearchAgents extends TickerBehaviour {

        public SearchAgents(Agent a, long period) {
            super(a, period);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTick() {
            DFAgentDescription template;
            ServiceDescription sd;
            DFAgentDescription[] result;

            // We search Seller Agents.
            sd = new ServiceDescription();
            sd.setName("Seller");

            template = new DFAgentDescription();
            template.addServices(sd);

            try {
                result = DFService.search(myAgent, template);

                if (result.length > 0) {
                    agricultores.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) 
                        seller.put(result[i].getName(), i); /*HERE IS THE PROBLEM, value needs to be price of seller product, not i*/
                } else {
                    // No agents where found.
                    agricultores.clear();
                    System.out.println("Not found.");
                } 
            } catch (FIPAException fe) {
                fe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to send an aclmessage to the seller to know about its price

Comment: Yeah, finally I did what you say and it worked! With the code I write up, I search de AID Agent, and when I find one, i save it in an array. So, when i got the agent, just sent de ACLMessage with the info and it is saved. Thank you for the answer! ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to give you any prices from your sellers. Here, you're just getting the list of all available sellers. The way to get prices is to send a message to each seller and ask for a price, then listen and get their according replies (prices).

First, send every seller a message.
In the **BuyerAgent** class:

```
ACLMessage msg = new ACLMessaage(ACLMessage.REQUEST);
msg.setContent("What's the price?");
for(DFAgentDescription df : results) {
    msg.addReceiver(df.getName());
}
myAgent.send(msg);
block();
```

In the **SellerAgent** class:

```
ACLMessage msg = myAgent.receive(MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.REQUEST));
if(msg != null) {
    ACLMessage reply = msg.createReply();
    reply.setPerformative(ACLMessage.PROPOSE);
    reply.setContent(**YOUR PRICE HERE**);
    myAgent.send(reply);
}
block();
```

Again, in the **BuyerAgent** class:

```
msg = myAgent.receive(MessageTemplate.MatchPerformative(ACLMessage.PROPOSE));
if(msg != null) {
    sellers.put(msg.getSender(), Integer.parseInt(msg.getContent());
    ...
}
```

**Note:**
The types of ACLMessages I used here (*REQUEST, PROPOSE*) are not as important. You can change them as you wish.